# Remove Labels in a Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django, forms, label, django-crispy-forms

Does anybody know if there is a correct way to remove labels in a crispy form?

I got as far as this:

```
self.fields['field'].label = ""
```

But it's not a very nice solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could edit the `field.html` template:
https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/templates/bootstrap/field.html#L7

Add a `FormHelper` attribute to your form that controls the label rendering and use it in that template `if`. Custom `FormHelper` attributes are not yet officially documented, because I haven't had time, but I talked about them in a keynote I gave, here are the slides:
https://speakerdeck.com/u/maraujop/p/django-crispy-forms

Comment: `page not found`

Answer (score 51):

Just do:

```
self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

To remove all labels.

Comment: Hides the label for checkboxes and radio buttons :(

Comment: ``self.fields['MYFIELD'].label = False`` to disable for a specific field

Comment: I tried both `form_show_labels = False` and override a specific field with `self.fields['validation_CGU'].label = True` and it didn't work, seems like the global rule takes priority, too bad

Comment: @YannicHamann 's solution worked for me. I think this needs to be highlighted as a separate answer.

Comment: Note this only works for Bootstrap [per the docs](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/form_helper.html?highlight=form_show_labels#bootstrap-3-helper-attributes).

Comment: @Vadorequest See the code for showing lable on specific field when all is False. See my reply

Answer (score 21):

Works with Boostrap ( [see documentation](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html?highlight=form_show_labels) )

In your form :

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from django import forms

class MyForm(forms.Form):
    [...]
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

In your template:

```
<form method='POST' action=''>{% csrf_token %}
{% crispy form %}
<input type='submit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-default'>
</form>
```

Comment: thank you - it works just as described. I added  the function in my form and it just worked

Answer (score 7):

The solution below lets you remove a label from both a regular or crispy control.  Not only does the label text disappear, but the space used by the label is also removed so you don't end up with a blank label taking up space and messing up your layout.

The code below works in django 2.1.1.

```
# this class would go in forms.py
class SectionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # add a custom field for calculation if desired
    txt01 = forms.CharField(required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' remove any labels here if desired
        '''
        super(SectionForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # remove the label of a non-linked/calculated field (txt01 added at top of form)
        self.fields['txt01'].label = ''

        # you can also remove labels of built-in model properties
        self.fields['name'].label = ''

    class Meta:
        model = Section
        fields = "__all__"
```

I'm not clear what the problem the OP had with the code snippet he showed, except that he wasn't putting the line of code in the right place.  This seems like the best and simplest solution.

Answer (score 4):

if you are only to remove some labels from input, then explicitly don't give a label name in model definition, i.e:

```
field = models.IntegerField("",null=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

**To Remove All Labels:**

```
self.helper.form_show_labels = False
```

To Show Specific Lable **when all False** :

```
HTML('<span>Your Label</span>')
```

To Disable Label for Specific field **when all is True**

```
self.fields['fieldName'].label = True
```

**Example:**

```
     Row(
            HTML('<span> Upolad Government ID (Adhar/PAN/Driving Licence)</span>'),
            Column('IdProof',css_class='form-group col-md-12 mb-0'),
            css_class='form-row'
        ),
```

Comment: <span> is not a label, and won't work if you change anything centrally in your css. Don't do that. If you need to show **some** labels and others not, just use tha `.label` way for each.

Answer (score 0):

This way you can remove label from field, or change default label text.

```
class ModelNameForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = OfferResidential
        fields = ['field_with_label', 'field_no_label']
        
        # all field mentioned here, with value '' will be shown without label
        labels = {
            'field_no_label': '',
        }
```