# show only input in django_crispy_from?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

How to show only the input field in Django crispy form.

```
<div class="">
     {{form1.username|as_crispy_field}}
</div>
```

[image]

how can it only show input field

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove labels from certain fields then you can do so by adding this to the `Class` responsible for your form.

```
self.fields['some_field'].label = False
```

Where `some_field` is the name of the field whose label you want to remove.

You can also [see the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11472495/remove-labels-in-a-django-crispy-forms) for different solutions to this problem.